# How can I limit the number of participant roles?

Tags: roles

We are using CiviCRM to coordinate volunteer registration to work events. As such, the event form has the "Participant Role" field. Is there away to limit the role of, say, "Lighting Designer," to one member and have it not be an option once the role is filled?

If there's a better way of doing this please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

You should use CiviVolunteer to manage and track volunteers for your event. Your requirement works our of the box with CiviVolunteer

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civivolunteer